# Asynchronous path update when a fetch is done in a test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Using react-testing-library I want to test that the application redirects to an error page if a fetch produces an error.

My app does that successfully. However, it's not working in the tests. Perhaps because the fetch is done asynchronously.

```
describe("<SignUp /> routing", () => {

  it('navigates to signup page', () => {
    const { getByTestId, history } = renderWithRouter(<App />);
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/');
    const headerSignUpLink = getByTestId("nav-header-signup");
    fireEvent.click(headerSignUpLink);
    // this works fine
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/signup');
  }

  it('when signup for encounters an error it redirects to error page', async () => {
    const { getByTestId, history } = renderWithRouter(
      <App />, { route: '/signup' }
    );

    // all good 
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/signup');
    const formSignUpButton = getByTestId("button-submit");

    // this click fires an asynchronous fetch
    fireEvent.click(formSignUpButton); 

    // The fetch fails on purpose. Now the app should be redirected to an error page. In my browser this works fine. However in the test it doesn't

    // Now this is where the test fails. The path is not seen as updated:
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/error');
  });
});
```

error in *'when signup for encounters an error it redirects to error page'*:

```
Expected: "/error"
Received: "/signup"
```

The renderWithRouter method used above is coming from source: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router

Any idea how to wait for the fetch to fail and redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [`wait`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#wait)?

```
await wait(() => expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/error'))
```